# Accept Multiple Image Extensions In Django Default Profile Page

Tags: image, django-models

I am trying to make a default user profile image in Django that accepts **BOTH** `jpg` and `png` extensions in `models.py`.

Currently `jpg` works, but if I change `default.jpg` to `default.png` both the code and the actual default image, the image does not show up.

Is there a way to tell Django to accept both extensions ?

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    users = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics') # accept default.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate the file extension using a [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/validators/#module-django.core.validators).

```py
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator


class Profile(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(
        validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['jpg', 'png'])]
    )
```

If the file name itself is important then you could write your own validator or rename the file after it's been uploaded by the user.